# Prove that a set A is semi-decidable if and only if there is a polynomial time relation R(x,y)

Tags: turing-machines

I know if there is a decidable relation R(x,y) for x in A, then A is semi-decidable. But how can I prove the relation is polynomial time?

For R(x,y), x is  where M is a TM, y is the accepting configuration of M. Is this a polynomial-time relation?

Answer (score 1):

> For $R(x,y)$, $x$ is where $M$ is a TM, $y$ is the accepting configuration of $M$. Is this a polynomial-time relation?

Yes that is the right idea. Except $y$ should be a *sequence* of configurations that starts in the initial configuration and ends in the accepting configuration.

To see why this works, we have to consider the running time of the TM that accepts $R(x, y)$. First the TM looks at the input $x$, and then it looks at the sequence of configurations $y$. The sequence of configurations looks something like a table:

```
Tape at time 0: x1 x2 x3 .... xn 0 0 0 0 0 .... 0
                ^HEAD, state q0
Tape at time 1: x1 x2 x3 .... xn 0 0 0 0 0 .... 0
                   ^HEAD, state q1
Tape at time 2: x1  1 x3 .... xn 0 0 0 0 0 .... 0
                       ^HEAD, state q2
...
```

and so on. So how does our TM check if this is in $R(x, y)$? We should check to make sure that the initial configuration has $x$ on the tape. How long will this take? And then we should check that $y$ is a valid sequence of configurations of according to the transition behavior of $M$. How long will that take? Finally, we need to check that the last configuration in $y$ is accepting. How long will that take?

Comment: So it takes O(|x|) to check x is on the tape. O(|y|) to check y is a valid transition sequence. O(|x|) to check the last configuration in y is accepting, right?

Comment: @John Mostly right -- except for Turing machines checking two strings for equality is quadratic instead of linear, so $O(|x|)^2$ to check $x$ is on the tape. What matters is that this is polynomial in $|x|$.

Comment: Also checking the last config is accepting means you check that the head is in an accepting state; that should be at most $O(|y|)$ instead of $O(|x|)$. Probably much less than $|y|$ but $|y|$ is an upper bound.

Comment: Does this mean that all semi-decidable problems are in NP? i don't? get it or do we need some extra conditions such as y has to be polynomially long? thanks!

Comment: @DeeDee Sorry I don't have time to write a detailed answer right now :( Try asking a new question!